# When is on delete cascade unuseful?

Tags: mysql, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have a parent table say A and a child say B and B references A's primary key
so most people will use on delete cascade to modify the tables when they delete from the parent A.
My question is: is there any example of a situation that I WILL NOT need 'on delete cascade'?
When will it be not useful to use?

Comment: ecommerce system where you delete a category, which would delete all products in that category, and delete those products from any orders previously placed. "oops"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like Marc B's example, because products generally would not be "children" of a category. Products and Categories can overlap, with a many-to-many relationship.

I have ON DELETE SET NULL in situations where the data is still useful without the parent.

E.g.

Suppose you have a `translations` table that contains columns `id`,`translation_category`,`from_text`, `to_text`

That table contains various text to text translations. The `translation_category` is a foreign key that references a specific field where the translations would be primarily used. But you could also do queries that ignore that key to get a count of common `from_text` and `to_text` values, since they may be repeated for different `translation_category` values.

That data is still perhaps useful even if you happen to delete one of the `translation_category` parent records. So I would use ON DELETE SET NULL there.

Of course, that same schema could be changed to put `translation_category` into a many-to-many linking table, but the same principles still apply.

Answer (score 0):

During table maintenance/recovery, the DBA may temporarily turn off delete cascade so the parent table can be emptied and reloaded for example without damaging/affecting data outside the table.